# Making simple tests in C++

Tags: c++, compilation, program-entry-point

I need to make some simple tests in C++ (never done before). I'm working in visual studio 2010 and I've came across the built in test tab. But I really didn't like it and it seems way overcomplicated to me.

All I need is a custom main() method so I could launch quick console app and see if class performs as it should.

I decided to overcome this with preprocessor definitions by creating a wrapper launcher file, which would be the main starting point in program.

So, my main.cpp file contains:

```
#define DESIRED_TEST "some_test.cpp"

#ifndef DESIRED_TEST
#include "main_program.cpp"
#else
#include DESIRED_TEST
#endif
```

main_program.cpp is the file which runs the entire program (it has the main method in it).
As you see, if I define DESIRED_TEST and assign an include file, main_program.cpp is not included and only the test file is supposed to be built (which also has main method in it).
However, when it comes to compiling I get this output:

```
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: _main already defined in some_test.obj
1>main_program.obj : error LNK2005: _main already defined in some_test.obj
1>C:\....... : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

How should I tell the compiler that the main starting point in program is main.cpp and it should compile and link only according to that file, ignoring multiple definitions in all other object files?

---

Here's how I overcame this problem (the main.cpp file):

```
#define DESIRED_TEST "some_test.h"    

#ifndef DESIRED_TEST    

int main(int argc, char *argv[])    
{    
    // main program code here
}    

#else    

#include DESIRED_TEST    

int main() {    
    FUNCTION_CALL();    
}    

#endif
```

the some_test.h file:

```
void some_test();
#define FUNCTION_CALL some_test
```

Now all I need is for every test create new some_test.h and some_test.cpp file and define function call.

The reason I don't want to learn test standart in visual studio is because tests for the project of my level are really simple. I'll probably need to learn it in the future, but I'll learn it when stuff gets really deep and complicated.

Comment: `.cpp` files are conventionally not meant to be `#include`d, so VS is assuming you want them to be built separately regardless of the contents of `main.cpp`. Trying to undo that is just going to take you further into "this is weird" territory. Why not spend a little more time getting to know the built-in test functionality, and a little less time trying to fight against widely-held development conventions. :)

Comment: But  "main_program.cpp" is still in your project? (and get compiled separately?)

Comment: Well, it is perfectly legal to include a `.cpp` file, it just isn't good style. What including does is nothing but concatenate another file's content with the current file. This does not magically "break" anything, it just isn't pretty and isn't easy to follow. The error that the OP is seeing probably comes from having everything in the project and compiling everything at some point (depending on whether the macro is defined or not) and then rebuilding (_not clean_), so the linker picks up all definitions, which is a violation of ODR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VC treats `.cpp`  files as sources, that should be compiled separately, regrdless of the fact, that they are included somewhere. This is usual behavior and you'd better not try to change it.

Instead, you can

- Rename your `.cpp` files to `.h` or `.inc` and include header files instead
- Wrap code inside `.cpp` in guard like

  ```
  //some_test.cpp
  #ifdef DESIRED_TEST 

  //code

  #endif


  //main_program.cpp
  #ifndef DESIRED_TEST 

  //code 

  #endif
  ```

  Then you should not include `.cpp`s anywhere.
  `DESIRED_TEST` can be defined in common header or in project settings.
- *But the best soultion would be to study test framework, provided with Visual Studio and use it.*

Comment: You dont need to rename the files. You can just exclude it from the project (in the solution explorer)

Comment: @qPCR4vir, I believe, excluding files from project is a bad idea: you'll lose in clarity, you'll not be able to use project explorer for navigation, for example

Comment: Yes, you are right! I said a simpler idea, not a better one. Anyway, things like IntelliSence, Object Browser, or right-click on the include “instruction” to quick open the file will still work.

Answer (score 0):

But "main_program.cpp" is still in your project? (and get compiled separately?)

You have in main.cpp:(main.cpp is in the project)

```
#define DESIRED_TEST "some_test.cpp"

#ifndef DESIRED_TEST
#include "main_program.cpp"
#else
#include DESIRED_TEST
#endif
```

Now, simple exclude some_test.cpp and main_program.cpp from the project (in the solution explorer), but dont delete the files! Things like IntelliSence, Object Browser, or right-click on the include “instruction” to quick open the file will still work

Comment: Yes, everything is inside project.